# How to verify secure erasure of Android and Apple mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, deletion, data-recovery, apple

I'm aware of how to securely sanitise and verify the sanitisation of data from both HDDs and SSDs, but mobile phones complicate this due to being there a lot of proprietary layers standing between the storage hardware and the interface.

Specifically, how can one verify the data sanitisation of Android and Apple mobile devices respectively? Is there no alternative to letting the factory reset run and hoping that the device's implementation of it doesn't fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory reset, open the camera and let it record a movie in the highest resolution and framerate until all storage is full, factory reset again.

The first factory reset will free all storage, then the movie recording will fill up all the storage, overwriting everything, and the second factory reset deletes everything again. This will work even on older phones where the storage was not encrypted.

It's overkill on the newer versions, because the storage is fully encrypted and the first factory reset will destroy the key.

Comment: Interesting idea. Do you know for sure that this applies to both Android and Apple devices?

Comment: It applies to any device that stores data. Android, iPhone, sd-card, HDD... It fills the entire storage and deletes it.